# Creating a table with certain columns from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say we have a table A with 200 different columns. We want to select columns that contain a certain substring (e.g. the "host" substring in "host_id", "host_name", "average_host_rating"), and create a new table B with only those columns and their data imported from a .csv file.

I tried creating the new table manually, however this is not good practice and i want to improve the code by making it valid and functional even if i add more columns to table A.

Creating the table manually:

```
SELECT 
   listings.host_id,
   listings.host_url ,
   ..
   ..
   listings.host_name ,
   listings.host_since ,
INTO host_table
FROM listings
WHERE TRUE;
```

Trying to create the table in a better way:

```
CREATE TABLE B AS 
SELECT  *
FROM    A
WHERE  A::text LIKE '%host%'
```

I expected it to create table B with every column that contains 'host' in its name however it returned an exact copy of table A (and all its data). I tried different ways and methods of creating new tables, however the problem always was that i could not isolate only the columns with the specified substring ('host').

What could be wrong in my syntax, way of thinking or anything else?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create and call a function with parameters. The function will dynamically chose the columns from `information_schema.columns`.

Note that `where false` is used because you mentioned data will come from a csv file and not from the original table.

```
create or replace function 
   fn_gen_tab_text ( curr_tab_in text,tab_text_in TEXT, new_tab_in text)
 RETURNS void AS
  $body$
 declare v_sql TEXT;
  BEGIN
   select 'CREATE TABLE %I AS select ' || string_agg(column_name,',') 
        ||' from %I where false'
      into v_sql from information_schema.columns  
   where table_name = curr_tab_in
   and column_name like '%'||tab_text_in||'%';
   EXECUTE format (v_sql,new_tab_in,curr_tab_in);
 END $body$ language plpgsql
```

Call it as

```
select fn_gen_tab_text('host_table','host','new_table' );
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=97439bc32c1f367430917a7697ef357c)